# Problem with combinations and permutations

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I've a list, let's say `[(1,1,1),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)]` and I want to generate all the permutations of n elements in the q lenght list, discarding the equivalent. I mean:

Input

```
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Output

```
[[(1,1,1),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)], <----- keep this
[(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,0)], <----- keep this
[(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,0)], <----- disgard this
[(1,1,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,0)], <----- disgard this
[(1,1,0),(0,0,0),(1,0,0)], <----- keep this
...
...
...
...
[(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1)], <----- keep this
[(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,1)], <----- disgard this
[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,1)], <----- disgard this
[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)], <----- disgard this
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,0,1)], <----- disgard this
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1)], <----- disgard this
[(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(1,1,1)]] <----- keep this
```

This is a quite simple task with some nested for cicle, and sum for function, but I can't figure out a way to achieve this using ipertools.
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the rule for discarding ? Could you clarify ? Feel unclear for me^^

Comment: You want 3 sub_list of 3 in the list of 9; if two list of nine differs only for the position (and not for the sum) of the "1" in one of  the sub_list of 3, you discard it. Is like having 3 balls (the "1") that can be in 3 pots (the list of 3). You just want to keep the "real" different combination: [(1,1,0)(1,0,0)(0,0,0)] and [(1,0,1)(0,1,0)(0,0,0)] means both of them 2 balls in the first pot, 1 ball in the second pot, 0 ball in the third pot, so you discard ont of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to list all the possible ways to perform 3 discards from you list of items, each consisting of 3 cards. I suggest you to do a better mapping of your choices, like for example `[3, 2, 0]` instead of `[(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1)]` where `[3, 2, 0]` means starting indices of your list for each discard. This case can be illustrated as follows:

- `[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, take out items starting from `index=3`
- `[1,1,1,0,0,0]`, take out items starting from `index=2` ->
- `[1,1,0]`, take out items starting from `index=0` ->
- `[]`

The next step of solutions is to consider how all the possible choices of indices looks like. It's quite clear that:

- first index doesn't exceed 6 (since list has 9 items),
- second index doesn't exceed 3 (since list has 6 items)
- third index is 0 (since list has 0 items)

In general I suggest to generate all the possible choices and do discards manually for each choice:

```
from itertools import product
d = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
n = 3
starting_indices = [range(len(d)-(n-1)-n*m) for m in range(len(d)//n)]
choices = []
for idx_sequence in product(*starting_indices):
    current_d = d.copy()
    current_choice = []
    for id in idx_sequence:
        current_choice.append(current_d[id: id+n])
        del current_d[id: id+n]
    choices.append(current_choice)
print(choices)
```

#### Note:

Some of the choices might be duplicated

#### Update:

You can eliminate duplicated choices if you add these rows to your script:

```
choices = set([tuple(tuple(m) for m in n) for n in choices]) #if you need to remove duplicates
choices = [list(list(m) for m in n) for n in choices] #if you need to set type back
```

#### Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Tkx. Yes, plenty of duplicates here. The ideal solution should skip each "1" every 3 places to avoid duplicates...

Comment: It's not a big deal. I can eliminate them if I form a set of these elements. Unfortunately, it's possible to form a set only if all these elements are hashable. To resolve it, I need to replace all the lists with tuples.

Comment: Tks, seems perfect now :-)

Comment: The following problem you posted seems quite interesting because it seems hard for me to create iterations with no repetitions included. I feel like little bit cheating while using these `del` and `set` commands. Just try to be more clear to attract more opinions on this answer next time.

Comment: Well, I've tried different set, and doesn't work :-(, but the speed seems fantastic to me. I've tried your script with n=6 (six "1" in the d list, and d lenght = 24 (so, 6 times "1" and 18 times "0"). I've tried to change the numer "2" in the instruction range(len(d)-2-n*m with different values, and don't work. Where this "2" come from? I guessd it was (n-1) of the first example I gave, with n=3, but it seems I'm wrong. Can you clarify, pls?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't do a generalisation properly. It should be `n-1` instead. Example: if you have len(d) = 15 items and you cross out `n = 5` consecutive ones, you can do it in 11 possible ways because `11 = len(d) - n + 1`. I'm going to fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Thet's how you can get permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations 
permut = permutations([1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]) 

for i in list(permut): 
    print(i)
```

If you just want to delete all duplicates you may use sumpy:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
list(multiset_permutations([1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]))
```

If something other needed - feel free to ask.

Comment: Using permutations, I get all of the permutations. Maybe I need to explain the problem better. Let's say I have 3 pot, and each pot can contains up to 3 balls. So I can have 3 balls in the first pot (=(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), 2 balls in the first pot, 1 ball in the second pot, 0 ball in the first pot, 2 balls in the second pot, and so on.